# Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete

Tags: c++, c++11

> Create a function that takes a sentence and turns every "i" into "wi" and "e" into "we", and add "owo" at the end.

I was creating the function for the above question and received an error:

> Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete

Can anyone please help me with the fix?

```cpp
#include<string>

std::string owofied(std::string sentence) {
    int pos=0;
    for(int i =0 ; i<sentence.size(); i++)
    {
        if(sentence[i]=='i')
            sentence.replace(i,1,"wi");
        else if(sentence[i]=='e')
            sentence.replace(i,1,"we");
        pos=i;
    }
    sentence.insert(pos,"owo");
    return sentence;
}
```

Comment: Start with the sentence "i", and step through with a debugger and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code turns "e" into "we". But then it turns the "e" in "we" into "we", creating another "we" that also gets replaced.

One simple fix is to increment `i` an extra time after the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a `wi` or `we`, you are not incrementing `i` past that replacement, so the next iteration finds that new `i`/`e` and replaces it, and so on, and so on, endlessly, until the code either times out or runs out of memory.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <string>

std::string owofied(std::string sentence)
{
    std::string::size_type i = 0; 
    while (i < sentence.size())
    {
        if (sentence[i] == 'i')
        {
            sentence.replace(i, 1, "wi", 2);
            i += 2;
        }
        else if (sentence[i] == 'e')
        {
            sentence.replace(i, 1, "we", 2);
            i += 2;
        }
        else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return sentence + "owo";
}
```

Which can then be simplified a little by using [`std::string::find_first_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) to find the characters to replace, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>

std::string owofied(std::string sentence)
{
    std::string::size_type i = 0;
    char replacement[2] = { 'w', '?' };
    while ((i = sentence.find_first_of("ie", i, 2)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        replacement[1] = sentence[i];
        sentence.replace(i, 1, replacement, 2);
        i += 2;
    }
    return sentence + "owo";
}
```

Alternatively, since the "replacements" are really just "insertions" of `w`:

```cpp
#include <string>

std::string owofied(std::string sentence)
{
    std::string::size_type i = 0;
    while ((i = sentence.find_first_of("ie", i, 2)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        sentence.insert(i, 1, 'w'); // or: sentence.insert(i, "w", 1);
        i += 2;
    }
    return sentence + "owo";
}
```

Comment: Replacing your `do{}while()` with `while((i = sentence.find_first_of("ie", i, 2)) != std::string::npos)` eliminates frowned upon `while (true)`, clearly indicates an end-of-loop condition, avoids `break` from the middle of the loop and is a bit shorter.

Comment: @VladFeinstein good point, I have updated my examples. I generally stay away from doing assignments inside of `if` and `while` statements.